# Javascript in CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want when I click on checkbox of `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, one event Javascript is activated.

My form :

```
class fichePresentationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = ('Others','Others'),('Caraibes','Caraibes'))
    competences_form = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': 'listCompetences',}),")
```

My html :

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{ form.competences_form|bootstrap }}
                    </div>
```

My JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#listCompetences").click(function(){ 
        for (val in $("#listCompetences")){
            alert(val);
        }
    });
});
```

But when I click on a checkbox, many alert will display. The alert messages are "0","length", "context", "selector", "jquery", "constructor"...etc.

I want display "Others" and "Caraibes"...

Comment: The for structure you are using is looping all properties of object $("#listCompetences"), which is a jquery object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in You're not targeting which property you need. It would be easier to answer with the rendered html.

Comment: How use rendered html ? I'm novice in js...

Comment: Open your page and find view source code somewhere in the menu. It depends on your browser. In Chrome for example, you can simply add view-source: before your adress.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Django question: you are simply looping over the wrong thing. You almost never want to use `for ... in` in JavaScript, as it iterates over all the internal properties of the object.

Instead, use jQuery to explicitly choose the objects you want - in this case, the `option` elements in the `select`- and use the [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over them:

```
$("#listCompetences").click(function(){ 
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I try this code and many variants, nothing is display :/.              CheckboxSelectMultiple is :                      <ul>
  <li><input type='checkbox' name='...' ></li>
  ...
</ul>